# Active admin custom index with instant method column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

i have a user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :payments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :debts, dependent: :destroy

def balance
@balance = self.payments.sum(:amount) - self.debts.sum(:amount)
end

end
```

and i have index in user controller

```
index do 
selectable_column
column :id
column :name
column :identity_card
column :address
column :contact
column :balance
column :code
column :created_at
column :updated_at
actions
end
```

how to display the balance on the index with my instance method on the user model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  column 'Balance' do |user|
   user.balance
  end
```

[Documentation](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html)